# In Android, what is the best practice when declaring variables in a class

Tags: java, android, variables

Let's take an Activity class for example, i've seen that many developers use a private variable within the class itself to store a pointer for a widget and they initialize them onCreate event. What is the porpoise for doing that? Isn't that resource wasting by allocating a new variable that we don't really need? I mean, we can always get the object by calling findviewById and, in any case, storing it into a method variable when needed..

Comment: And if the same View is referred to in multiple methods? Makes more sense to only have to `find` it once, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, but from the performance and resource saving point of view.. what is best?

Comment: Performance is always better if you only have to find it once.

Comment: Performance and resource saving are directly at odds here. Caching findable things is a classic case of optimization for speed at the expense of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many instances of that view being used, code becomes more readable with a variable.

Also, it's marginally faster that looking it up on every usage, especially if there's a lot of usage. Even assuming the best search algorithm, `findViewById()` takes longer than variable access.

It's a microoptimization anyway; both the memory hit from an extra variable and the lookup time for `find` are so miniscule, the user won't notice the difference. The time a coder spends on overthinking such matters can probably be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: Yes that's what i meant. So, by using findViewById aren't we accessing the same memory reference than with a variable? I understand that it can help developers to type the code in a cleaner way, it's always easier to access `mMyTextView` that 'findViewById(R.id..)', but i'd like to know which is the best technique from a time or resource saving point of view.

Comment: Time is spent on getting to that memory reference, given an ID. See my comment above: what you want **more** - speed or memory? Both are negligible, by the way. It's all a microoptimization anyway; you shouldn't spend much time overthinking those.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of calls to `findViewById()`, that's a lot of different places where a typo could mean you're getting the *wrong* view back.  By putting the view into a field once, you ensure that you've only got one bit of code to get right.  Don't Repeat Yourself.

Conversely, though, you need to make sure that you don't try to access the field before your code has had a chance to initialise it.  This isn't usually a problem in practice, but I tend to prefer to make my classes as immutable as possible and not being able to initialise a field until some time after the constructor returns rankles.